# Is there a way to have a dynamic dataProvider?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am writing up unit test for a series of methods, each of which parses an xml string and returns an object<sup>1</sup>. I'm currently using [Data Providers](https://phpunit.de/manual/4.8/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers) to test different versions of the xml string. Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
class TestSubjectTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function employeeXmlProvider() {
        $array = [
            [
                '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><employee><status>1</status><name>John</name></employee></root>',
                true
            ],
            [
                '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><employee><status>0</status><name>Sally</name></employee></root>',
                false
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function customerXmlProvider() {
        $array = [
            [
                '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><customer><status>1</status><name>John</name></customer></root>',
                true
            ],
            [
                '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><customer><status>0</status><name>Sally</name></customer></root>',
                false
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider employeeXmlProvider
     */
    public function testMethodThatUsesEmployee($xml, $expectedStatus) {
        $testSubject = new TestSubject();
        $result = $testSubject->parseEmployeeAndReturnObject($xml);
        $this->assertInstanceOf(Person:class, $result);
        $this->assertEquals($expectedStatus, $result->active);
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider customerXmlProvider
     */
    public function testMethodThatUsesCustomer($xml, $expectedStatus) {
        $testSubject = new TestSubject();
        $result = $testSubject->parseCustomerAndReturnObject($xml);
        $this->assertInstanceOf(Person:class, $result);
        $this->assertEquals($expectedStatus, $result->active);
    }
}
```

The XML string that is used by each method varies only in the name of one of the top-level tags. In my example code above, the only difference between the two providers is that one uses an `employee` tag and the other uses a `customer` tag. There are many methods to test like this. I would like to know if it's possible to create just one data provider that can conditionally change the tag in the XML string **depending on what test function it is being used for**.

[1]: In my actual code, each of the methods actually calls a third party API which responds with XML. The API call is performed by a service that is passed into the constructor of the class being tested. I am using Mock objects to replace the data call return value with the XML string in my data providers. This detail wasn't important so in my example code above I just pass in the XML directly to the method.

Comment: Sure, what I would do is create a folder with just test files in it, then use something like `scan_dir` to scan the folder for xml input, then you could make another.  I would make them a short array like this would be the file `<?php return [ 'xml' => '<?xml version="1.0"..', 'resultClass` => Person::class];` then you can run them in a loop with scan_dir

Comment: @Ultimater Thanks, where would I save that class member. Could I do it through setUp? I'm new to unit tests.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I'm not sure what you are saying. Each method in each test_ function only works with the type of xml that they are expecting. So I can't just have all the xml types in an array. I need to return a customer xml only when I'm testing the customer function.

Comment: Here is an example I found with a quick search, but instead of an array what I do is make each nested array a file with an array and inputs in it, then the dataProvider constructs the array by sucking those in  https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/phpunit/data-providers  If you see where they set this up `getSpecificationTests` that was what I mean but instead just pull files in that way you can just drop in new test files and it will pull them in.

Comment: I got nothing, dataProviders work differently than I thought. Only advice I got is use a different provider for each test so you know which test is using it, then simply have all the dataProviders call the same method, with an extra argument, so you can make the variant in data you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets look at what is the same with these

```
/**
 * @dataProvider employeeXmlProvider
 */
public function testMethodThatUsesEmployee($xml, $expectedStatus) {
    $testSubject = new TestSubject();
    $result = $testSubject->parseEmployeeAndReturnObject($xml);
    $this->assertInstanceOf(Person:class, $result);
    $this->assertEquals($expectedStatus, $result->active);
}

/**
 * @dataProvider customerXmlProvider
 */
public function testMethodThatUsesCustomer($xml, $expectedStatus) {
    $testSubject = new TestSubject();
    $result = $testSubject->parseCustomerAndReturnObject($xml);
    $this->assertInstanceOf(Person:class, $result);
    $this->assertEquals($expectedStatus, $result->active);
}
```

This is what I see

```
/**
 * @dataProvider genericXmlProvider
 */
public function testGenericMethod($parsemethod, $xml, $resultclass, $expectedStatus) {
    $testSubject = new TestSubject();
    //you could throw an if(!method_exists($testSubject, $parsemethod)) throw new .... in here if you want.
    $result = $testSubject->{$parsemethod}($xml);
    $this->assertInstanceOf($resultclass, $result);
    $this->assertEquals($expectedStatus, $result->active);
}
```

So in the basic form you need the provider to pass these extra 2 things in.

```
public function genericXmlProvider(){
  $array = [
        [
            'parseEmployeeAndReturnObject',
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><customer><status>1</status><name>John</name></customer></root>',
             Person:class,
             true
        ],
        [
            'parseEmployeeAndReturnObject',
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><customer><status>0</status><name>Sally</name></customer></root>',
             Person:class,
            false
        ],
        [
            'parseCustomerAndReturnObject',
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><customer><status>1</status><name>John</name></customer></root>',
             Person:class
            true
        ],
        [               
            'parseCustomerAndReturnObject',
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><customer><status>0</status><name>Sally</name></customer></root>',
             Person:class
            false
        ]
    ];
}
```

So now we have effectively merged these together. We can agree on this, right. If you pass in the parse function as a string, and the result class also as a string then we can unify these methods. Correct?

However, as you can see this will very quickly get "out of hand" and be a real nightmare to maintain.  So instead of having to edit an maintain this huge array of "Stuff" what I would do is make a folder for "test" files to go in.  I'll just call it "providerTests" in this folder we will put each of these as their own mini-PHP files.

Here is an example of just the first array I will call it `emptest1.php`.

```
<?php
    return 
       [
            'parseEmployeeAndReturnObject',
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><customer><status>1</status><name>John</name></customer></root>',
             Person:class,
             true
        ];
```

Now what this does is in the provider instead of this big sinking array, we can pull the data from `providerTests` and construct our array.

```
public function genericXmlProvider(){
     $providers = array_diff(scandir(__DIR__.'/providerTests'), ['.', '..']);
     $data = [];
     foreach($providers as $provider){

         $item = require $provider;
         //this is optional, I thought I would toss in a bit of validation on the input files. You could make them classes and have an interface etc. but that might be overkill.
         if(!is_array($item)) throw new Exception("Provider data error in file $provider");
         $data[] = $item;

     }
     return $data;
}
```

So now what we can do is just drop new files with these array providers or whatever you want to call them and they will get sucked in and returned by the provider to the test function.  This should make maintaining the test way more pleasant.

I haven't tested any of this, but it might work.... lol

**UPDATE**

One last idea is I would include the name of the file in the inputs to the method and in the file's array.  Then in the 'assert' message, I think it's the 3rd argument you can put that information in.  Then when a test fails we will have a way to backtrack to what file it came from.

So something like this

`emptest1.php`.

```
<?php
    return 
       [
            'parseEmployeeAndReturnObject',
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><customer><status>1</status><name>John</name></customer></root>',
             Person:class,
             true,
             __FILE__ //we will use the magic __FILE__ constant for back tracking
        ];
```

And then

```
/**
 * @dataProvider genericXmlProvider
 */
public function testGenericMethod($parsemethod, $xml, $resultclass, $expectedStatus, $providerSource) {
    $testSubject = new TestSubject();
    $result = $testSubject->{$parsemethod}($xml);
    $this->assertInstanceOf($resultclass, $result, "Provided by $providerSource");
    $this->assertEquals($expectedStatus, $result->active, "Provided by $providerSource");
}
```

Then when a test fails it will say something like:

```
"Provided by {path}/providerTests/emptest1.php"
```

And we can easily backtrack it to the provider stub that was injected.

Yes I'm brilliant, I know...

**UPDATE1**

In re.

> Actually I was hoping there was a way for my dataProvider to just return something like

Let's try to minimize this a bit, well add some complexity but it's one time complexity instead of all the time complexity of having many inputs in our "config" files.

For `Person:class` it's reasonable to assume that the object type won't change from one "type" to another "type" of the tests we need to do (and by we I mean you). For example the types are like "employee" or "customer".

We can eliminate the `parsemethod` and the `status` with some creative naming conventions for our filename.  We'll use a filename schema like this:

```
{parseMethod}_{status}_{instance}
```

Or we can shorten the method to

```
parseEmployee_0_1.xml
parseEmployee_1_1.xml

parseCustomer_0_1.xml
parseCustomer_1_1.xml
```

The file name `__FILE__` we can actually get when we compile the provider, as we have that from scandir.  Not sure why I didn't think of this.

This trims our config down from this:

```
<?php
    return 
       [
            'parseEmployeeAndReturnObject',
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><customer><status>1</status><name>John</name></customer></root>',
             Person:class,
             true
        ];
```

To just this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><customer><status>1</status><name>John</name></customer></root>
```

You may have noticed I changed the extension from `.php` to `.xml`. This is because we no longer need it to be PHP. All that is left to put in the body of the file now is the actual XML, of course this requires some extreme modification to our provider:

```
public function genericXmlProvider(){
     //these are common per type of object we are parsing, which is reasonable
     $default = [
         'employee' =>[
              'parseMethod'=>'parseEmployeeAndReturnObject',
              'resultClass' => Person::class
         ],
         'customer' =>[
              'parseMethod'=>'parseCustomerAndReturnObject',
              'resultClass' => Person::class
         ]               
     ];
     //dynamically compile the pattern based on the default array's keys
     $pattern = '/\/parse(?P<method>'.implode('|', array_keys($default)).')_(?P<status>[0-9])_[0-9]\.xml$/i';
     //should be this  \/parse(?P<method>employee|customer)_(?P<status>[0-9])_[0-9]\.xml$/i

     //scan for files and remove '.' and '..', which is typical of scandir
     $providers = array_diff(scandir(__DIR__.'/providerTests'), ['.', '..']);
     $data = [];
     foreach($providers as $providerSource){
         //parse the filename
        if(preg_match($pattern, $providerSource, $match){ 
             $xml = trim(file_get_contents($providerSource)); //trim just because we can
             //I put the argument names in so it's a bit easier to read
             $data[] = [
                 $default[$match['method']]['parseMethod'], //$parsemethod,
                 $xml,
                 $default[$match['method']]['resultClass'], //$resultclass,
                 $match['status'], // $expectedStatus,
                 $providerSource
             ];
        }else{
            //[optional] throw error for no filename match
        }

     }
     return $data;
}
```

This should minimize the amount of "Stuff" you need in each of the input files, which is good.  This works as long as we stick to the naming convention for the filenames.  This has some advantages and disadvantages.  It makes the provider a bit more complex and adds the naming convention restrictions to the filename, which is not necessarily a bad thing in it of itself, as it can aid in organizing the files and keep the names sensible.

One minor disadvantage is we may have to change some code if we add a type in, where before it was contained solely in the file body.  But the amount of code we need to add is minimal when compared to just using a large array for this, and in the long run it's more D.R.Y.

Fortunately, we don't have to refactor the test method at all as we maintained the same inputs, we just changed how we store them.

See we can minimize the individual requirements of each file, if we want.  We can do anything we want to imagine with PHP.  It's pretty cool, actually.  And as a bonus you got to witness the process I go through to work my way from nothing to something grand... lol.

Comment: Awesome that looks pretty good. I didn't even think about factoring out the method names.

Comment: I had `__DIR__` as `__DOR_` for some weird reason, and I added a bit of backtracking utility that should come in quite handy.  My motto is you have to write something at least 3 times to get it right...

Comment: I really love returning an array config like that, it's sort of my new thing, well new for the last 2 years or so, but I keep finding new creative uses for it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Actually I was hoping there was a way for my dataProvider to just return something like `"<?xml ...><root><$tagname><status>1</status><name>John</name></$tagname>"` and just use different $tagname for each test because it feels like everything else is repetition. But I guess there is no way to do that.

Comment: Yeah, I know a lot of Laravel codebases use it for config related stuff so you can call `config('something.somethingelse')` and it grabs something.php expecting an array, then grabs the key somethingelse. If I recall correctly, it's always been a feature of PHP, but only in more recent times, it's been looked at again for its power of returning arrays and arguably considered good design.

Comment: You could use a naming convention that would fill in the method.  If `Person:class` is always the same you could name the files like `Employee_test_1` and then use something like `/\/([a-z]+)_/` in preg_match and switch on the first match for the function.  I can do an update with it.

Comment: @KodosJohnson you can always have the data provider return a template like, then use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) within your specific test to toss in the variable change. Or dare I say, eval so it evaluates the string within the context of the test to grab the variable `$tagname`.

Comment: @KodosJohnson - Ok I am done, I got it down to just putting the XML in the file and a  pretty sensible naming convention for the filenames.  With a bit of Regex magic (which I am quite proficient at) we can pull it all together pretty nicely.  I do stuff like this all day long... refactoring code, tweaking this and that....  I find it enjoyable, in a weird programmer way.